# SQLite How can I select data between 2 date with time included

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have seperate date and time columns in my table. Date as mm/dd/yyyy, time as hh:mm but i can change the format. I want to list data between 2 date/time. How can I do that?

```
select * from testtable where date >= '01/10/2022' AND date <= '01/10/2023' AND time >= '13:45' AND time <= '15:50'
```

I wrote it but of course it doesn't work like what i expected.

Answer (score 1):

The best fix and really the only one you want here would be to start storing your timestamps in a sortable ISO format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss`.  Then, use this query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM testtable
WHERE date BETWEEN '2022-01-10 13:45:00' AND '2023-01-10 15:50:00';
```

The thing to realize here is that SQLite does not actually have a date column type.  Rather, you always store your dates/timestamps as *text*, and therefore it is crucial to use an ISO sortable format as shown above.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Should i need to add seconds part?

Comment: Something is weird here. i put values to date column in "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm"  format. If i run query with "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm" format, it doesnt work right. But if i execute query in "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm" format, it list data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If your target is sqlite, it lacks complex timestamp types. But you have another option here. You can store that as unix timestamp, it is an integer representing the number of seconds offset from the epoch which is `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`. The table format would then be:

```sql
CREATE TABLE testtable (
    date INTEGER
);
```

You can the use the `unixepoch` function to translate a string representation to that unix timestamp format. To insert a new date, you would use:

```sql
INSERT INTO testtable (date) VALUES (unixepoch('2023-01-11T11:30:00+01:00'))
```

Finding a matching row is now as easy to compare integers together. You can convert the datetime representation to unix timestamp at the application level, most programming environments provide such time utility functions/library. Or can still use the `unixepoch` function from sqlite for your where clause.

```sql
SELECT * FROM testtable
WHERE date >= unixepoch('2022-10-01T13:45:00Z')
   AND date <= unixepoch('2023-10-01T15:50:00Z')
```

The final `Z` indicates an UTC time zone but you can adjust that with another `+HH:00` extenstion instead which reflect the offset from utc of your datetime representation.